# Problem with roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I am having a few problems with roots. This is apart of a larger question where I am taking the derivative of of a function. I know I got the first part right (answer key) but when I plug in root 2 and do some maths (attempt to) something goes terribly wrong. Expanding the denominator doesn't seem to help either... Any hints would be welcome!

[image]

Comment: Irrevelant to the question, but what language is the pic written on?

Comment: What do you mean by language?

Comment: How did you generate it?

Comment: I just made it in paint :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well those are the same! $$\dfrac{2-2\sqrt{2}}{(\sqrt2-1)^2}=\dfrac{2(1-\sqrt{2})}{(1-\sqrt{2})^2}=\dfrac2{1-\sqrt2}.$$
For the first manipulation in the numerator we factored $2$, and for the denominator note that $(\sqrt2-1)^2=(1-\sqrt{2})^2$ since $(\alpha)^2=(-\alpha)^2$. The rest consists of canceling.

Comment: I did now know I could just switch the negative around when the terms are being squared like that. In doing the math now it seems so obvious.

Comment: @Crispy You're welcome, glad I could help ! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

What you got is correct, and note that
$$\frac{2-2\sqrt 2}{(\sqrt 2-1)^2}=\frac{2(1-\sqrt 2)}{(1-\sqrt 2)^2}=\frac{2}{1-\sqrt 2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{2x(x-1)-x^2}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{x^2-2x}{(x-1)^2}$
plugging $x=\sqrt{2}$ in this term
$\frac{2-2\sqrt{2}}{(\sqrt{2}-1)^2}=\frac{2(1-\sqrt{2})}{(-\sqrt{2}+1)^2}=\frac{2}{1-\sqrt{2}}$